# gstreamer desktop rtsp streaming delayed by 4 seconds

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I am using the below command to stream my desktop screen over rtsp from a vc++ app.

```
dx9screencapsrc startx=1280 use-damage=0 ! video/x-raw,framerate=15/1 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay pt=96 name=pay0
```

The output is currently delayed by about 4 seconds. I was wondering if there is a way to fix this delay or reduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `tune=zerolatency` option for the `x264enc`element.

P.S. I don't think `use-damage` and `startx` are valid options for `dx9screencapsrc`. These are for the `ximagesrc` element for X11 screens.

Comment: helped in reducing the latency to around 1-2 seconds!